# Gridview paging not working after upgrading to .Net 4.6

Tags: asp.net, gridview, .net-4.6

After bumping my head around for several days I decided to ask for help since I'm stuck with what I think might be a .Net 4.6 bug.

I had a gridview with an object datasource with paging (bellow is a simplified version), and all was working fine. Some day after the regular Windows updates the gridview started having a strange behaviour (I'll explain later), and after trouble shooting I realized that it that was due to the .Net 4.6 upgrade that had been installed. I was able to reproduce the problem on several Windows 2012 R2 machine and Windows 8.1 (including one with Visual Studio 2013), and when I removed the .Net 4.6 everything started working again.

I had a Windows 8.1 with VS 2015 so I tested it there and was also able to reproduce the problem (on VS2015 I can't remove .Net 4.6 because it is a requirement for VS2015). To further debug the problem I kept using that VS2015.

To make the explanation easier I'm posting the VS2015 version which is a stripped down version of the original gridview, and that I've been using for testing.

```
<%@ Page Title="Top of Shame" Language="C#" CodeBehind="HallOfShame.aspx.cs" Inherits="SissdwWebSite.Siss.SwingWorker.HallOfShame" EnableViewState="false" %>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:GridView
        ID="GvSwingWorkersOfShame" runat="server" DataSourceID="DsSwingWorkersOfShame" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerSettings-Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" 
        AllowPaging="True" AllowCustomPaging="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Pos." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <p></p>

    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="DsSwingWorkersOfShame" runat="server" EnablePaging="true"
        SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="SissdwWebSite.DataLayer.SissdwTableAdapters.HallOfShameTableAdapter"
        SelectCountMethod="GetHallOfShameCount">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="CodOper" Type="String" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="false" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
</form>
</body>
```

The gridview was expected to produce a list like the one bellow (original version had about 10 columns but I stripped it down to just the first one with a row number to keep things easier to understand). The output was HTML but I wasn't able to reproduce it here but you get the idea.

Pos.

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10
```

<<<>>>

Now the issue: On the code above, the gridview works exactly as expected. If I put that custom pager bellow (or other several combinations that I tried), the gridview starts lagging one click behind.

```
        <PagerTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 30%">
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="First" CommandArgument="First" CommandName="Page">
                            <img id="imgFirst" runat="server" src="~/images/2leftarrow.png" height="16" width="16" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Prev" CommandArgument="Prev" CommandName="Page">
                            <img id="imgPrev" runat="server" src="~/images/1leftarrow.png" height="16" width="16" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Next" CommandArgument="Next" CommandName="Page">
                            <img id="imgNext" runat="server" src="~/images/1rightarrow.png" height="16" width="16" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Last" CommandArgument="Last" CommandName="Page">
                            <img id="imgLast" runat="server" src="~/images/2rightarrow.png" height="16" width="16" />
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </PagerTemplate>
```

By lagging one click behind, I mean, on the first time I click on the forward arrow, nothing happens on the result that is displayed (but PageIndex moves from 0 to 1). The second time, it shows position 11-20 and internally the PageIndex moves from 1 to 2, etc.

Further down the line if I click on the "go to first", it will only go to the first page when I do some other action (ie, it's always lagging behind one command). I don't know if this very clear, but had a small label showing the current page and it show one "page behind" my last command.

Please remember that if I remove the pager template all goes well, and on .Net 4.5.2 everything was working well, no matter the pager template.

I tried to debug the .Net 4.6 framework but I wasn't able to understand enough of it to figure out what was going on.

In summary: is it .Net 4.6 bug, or am I missing something? Is there a way to make my gridview work properly again on .Net 4.6, either by fixing my code or due to some other workaround?

Any suggestions to further troubleshoot the issue are well come...

EDIT: some extra clarification on the issue. I'm printing PageIndex on each stage in several event handlers.
On initial page load

```
Page_Load =0
GvSwingWorkersOfShame_DataBinding =0
GvSwingWorkersOfShame_DataBound =0

Pos.

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10
```

After clicking forward on time:

```
Page_Load =0
GvSwingWorkersOfShame_DataBinding =0
GvSwingWorkersOfShame_DataBound =0
GvSwingWorkersOfShame_PageIndexChanging =0
GvSwingWorkersOfShame_PageIndexChanged =1
GvSwingWorkersOfShame_DataBinding =1
GvSwingWorkersOfShame_DataBound =1

Pos.

1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10
```

Comment: After more troubleshooting, I managed to narrow it down do the EnableViewState. With .Net 4.5.2 it would work with EnableViewState="false" at the page level, with 4.6 it won't work even if I set EnableViewState="true" at the gridview and/or the datasource. But if I set it at the page level, it works fine. The problem is that on the original site the page is being inherited from a master page and I will need to turn it on the and that will affect the whole site :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a regression in 4.6.1. The bug has been fixed in 4.6.1. You can install [4.6.1 RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2015/10/29/announcing-net-framework-4-6-1-rc.aspx) to verify the fix and wait for the RTM which should be released soon.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look and I'll post back.